# Need Assistance with DLRS Test Code

Tags: dlrs

I'm getting an error for the Timecard object and needing to write a test code for a DLRS rollup. My parent object is the Milestones in PSA and I'm rolling up the total hours field from the Timecard header.

Error:

> dlrs_pse_Timecard_HeaderTest.testTrigger System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Timecard Header must specify a Project.: [pse__Project__c] Class.dlrs.RollupService.testHandler: line 282, column 1 Class.dlrs_pse_Timecard_HeaderTest.testTrigger: line 11, column 1

I'm not a developer and would like to know what exactly I need to put in the Developer Console's Execute Anonymous Window. I believe I need to use the "TimecardProjectSelectorTest" apex class but not sure if that's correct or what else I need to format everything correctly in the window.

Comment: As dlrs is a managed package, you should not have any problems with failing unit tests. You can still migrate your rollup definitions, install the package, etc.

Comment: @AdrianLarson This appears to be the autogenerated test class for a dynamically-deployed trigger from DLRS, which isn't part of the managed package. I presume the error is blocking the deployment of a child trigger, Christina?

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I have used the package quite a bit. :) I've never had the test classes present a problem despite extensive usage.

Comment: Yes, the error is preventing the deployment of the child trigger. Others have said I need a Test Code but I don't know how to create one.

Comment: The best resource for DLRS support is the [community success group here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5pCAE)

Answer (score 3):

The DLRS-autogenerated test classes look like this (I copied one of mine that is on OrderItem:

```
/**
 * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs)
 **/
@IsTest
private class dlrs_OrderItemTest
{
    @IsTest
    private static void testTrigger()
    {
        // Force the dlrs_OrderItemTrigger to be invoked, fails the test if org config or other Apex code prevents this.
        dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new OrderItem());
    }
}
```

If you have some VR rule or Required Field config that requires a specific field to be present, you need to modify the line:

```
dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new OrderItem()
```

to include more arguments like

```
dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new OrderItem(Foo__c = 'val'));
```

The DLRS comment

```
// Force the dlrs_OrderItemTrigger to be invoked, fails the test if org config or other Apex code prevents this.
```

even says why the test may fail.  In your use case, it appears some lookup object (pse__Project__c) is required on the insert of the detail object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your willingness to assist me! Another consultant gave me a work around without having to mess with code. Instead of using the Timecard Header object, I used the Timecard split which allowed the child trigger to deploy for the rollup.

Comment: Please use comments to say thank you, apart from that your answer is fine as a it specifies how you have created a work around.